# Fluentd log source format RegEX

Tags: regex, fluentd

I have logs of this format:

```
2015-02-25 18:33:06,975 INFO c.a.p.c.b.s.Monitor akka://application/user/daemons/monitor : 91 active threads, 4175691776 bytes used
```

I came up to this regex:

```
(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<method>[^ ]*) (?<path>[^ ]*) (?<message>[^ ].*$)
```

When I test in [Fluentular](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%28%3F%3Ctime%3E%5B%5E+%5D*+%5B%5E+%5D*%29+%28%3F%3Cmethod%3E%5B%5E+%5D*%29+%28%3F%3Cpath%3E%5B%5E+%5D*%29+%28%3F%3Cmessage%3E%5B%5E+%5D.*%24%29&input=2015-02-25+18%3A33%3A06%2C975+INFO++c.a.p.c.b.s.Monitor+akka%3A%2F%2Fapplication%2Fuser%2Fdaemons%2Fmonitor+%3A+91+active+threads%2C+4175691776+bytes+used&time_format=%25F+%25T%2C%25L)
(I will be using it as a format for fluentd log input) I get
fields:

```
time  =>    2015/02/25 18:33:06 +0000
method  =>    INFO
PATH    =>  <empty>
message => c.a.p.c.b.s.Monitor akka://application/user/daemons/monitor : 91 active threads, 4175691776 bytes used
```

I am not able to break the message string. I would like the matching groups to be:

```
time  =>    2015/02/25 18:33:06 +0000
method  =>    INFO
PATH  =>    c.a.p.c.b.s.Monitor
message =>    akka://application/user/daemons/monitor : 91 active threads, 4175691776 bytes used
```

What would be a proper regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there are two spaces between `INFO` and `c.a.p.c.b.s.Monitor` in your input string.  Adding a `+` to allow for one-or-more spaces in that position, you'd get:

```
(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<method>[^ ]*) +(?<path>[^ ]*) (?<message>[^ ].*$)
```

You may or may not want to add those to the rest of the components, like:

```
(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ]*) +(?<method>[^ ]*) +(?<path>[^ ]*) +(?<message>[^ ].*$)
```